# Laravel - Insert ao banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel

Sou Novo no Laravel e estou tentando inserir ao banco de dados uns datos porem ele continua dando erro n sei se estou fazendo certo 
como estou fazendo:

```
   $nome=$_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome=$_POST['sobrenome'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $senha=$_POST['senha'];
    $diaN=$_POST['nascdia'];
    $mesN=$_POST['nascmes'];
    $anoN=$_POST['nascano'];
    $cpf=$_POST['cpf'];
    $console=$_POST['console'];
    $game=$_POST['game'];
    if(isset($_POST['resp_legal_nome'])){
    $nomeR=$_POST['resp_legal_nome'];
    }else{
        $nomeR="Sou de maior";
    }
    if(isset($_FILES['foto'])){
        function gerahasc($tamanho = 100, $maiusculas = true, $numeros = true, $simbolos = false)
                            {
                                // Caracteres de cada tipo
                                $lmin = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
                                $lmai = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                                $num = '1234567890';
                                $simb = '!@#$%*-';

                                // Variáveis internas
                                $retorno = '';
                                $caracteres = '';

                                // Agrupamos todos os caracteres que poderão ser utilizados
                                $caracteres .= $lmin;
                                if ($maiusculas) $caracteres .= $lmai;
                                if ($numeros) $caracteres .= $num;
                                if ($simbolos) $caracteres .= $simb;

                                // Calculamos o total de caracteres possíveis
                                $len = strlen($caracteres);

                                for ($n = 1; $n <= $tamanho; $n++) {
                                // Criamos um número aleatório de 1 até $len para pegar um dos caracteres
                                $rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
                                // Concatenamos um dos caracteres na variável $retorno
                                $retorno .= $caracteres[$rand-1];
                                }

                                return $retorno;
                            }
                            $_FILES['foto']['nome']=gerahasc();
                            include 'carregarFT.php';



    }else{
        $foto="Sem_FT.png"; 
    }

    $nick=$_POST['nickname'];
    $estado=$_POST['estado'];
    $cidade=$_POST['cidade'];
    $hoje=date('d/m/Y');
    $hasc=gerahasc();

    DB::insert('INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`Nome`, `Sobrenome`, `Email`, `Senha`, `NascDia`, `NascMes`, `NascAno`, `Cpf`, `NomeResponsavel`, `Console`, `Game`, `Ninck`, `Estado`, `Cidade`, `Qtdjogo`, `Vitorias`, `Derrotas`, `Empate`, `Vitoriawo`, `Derrotawo`, `Banido`, `Sinalizado`, `Bloqueado`, `Utimologin`, `Ativo`, `Has`, `Voucher`) VALUES ('$nome','$sobrenome','$email','$senha',$diaN,'$mesN',$anoN,$cpf,'$nomeR','$console','$game','$nick','$estado','$cidade',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'$hoje',1,'$hasc',2)')
```

erro que esta voltando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Procure categorizar melhor suas perguntas, isso não tem nada a ver com o Laravel, até porque você não está utilizando ele da maneira que deveria, o erro no seu código é apenas um erro simples de sintaxe.
Quando for utilizar um framework procure ler a documentação antes de sair usando, você está jogando todos os recursos dele no lixo, fazendo seu método dessa forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tá iniciando e fechando o script sql com aspas simples (') e a cada value de varchar que você vai inserir também usa aspas simples. Isso faz o php interpretar que a cada aspas simples que você usa tá interrompendo a string. Tenta abrir e fechar o script com aspas duplas(") e usar as aspas simples só nos campos varchar do insert que vai resolver seu problema.

Tipo assim:

```
DB::insert("INSERT INTO `usuarios`(`Nome`, `Sobrenome`, `Email`, `Senha`, `NascDia`, `NascMes`, `NascAno`, `Cpf`, `NomeResponsavel`, `Console`, `Game`, `Ninck`, `Estado`, `Cidade`, `Qtdjogo`, `Vitorias`, `Derrotas`, `Empate`, `Vitoriawo`, `Derrotawo`, `Banido`, `Sinalizado`, `Bloqueado`, `Utimologin`, `Ativo`, `Has`, `Voucher`) VALUES ('$nome','$sobrenome','$email','$senha',$diaN,'$mesN',$anoN,$cpf,'$nomeR','$console','$game','$nick','$estado','$cidade',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'$hoje',1,'$hasc',2)")
```

Comment: agora esta dando esse erro
SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range

Comment: Isso é um problema em algum campo numérico. Dá uma olhada se todos os tipos de campos tão compatíveis e se encaixam no valores passados no insert, incluindo o tamanho dos campos e até mesmo as casas decimais.